# IdentityServer4 storing and accessing user credentials in a distributed application scenario

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4

Since there is no forum to IdentityServer or I did not find it, I try to find an answer here.

I think I can use IdentityServer in one of my projects. But it seems that I have a problem understanding the usage and the design I'm striving for.

I looked at the IdentityServer quickstarts and understood and tested the example with an authenticated application. In the example, a client is registered to access an API with a client secret.

```
{
    return new[]
    {
        // client credentials flow client
        new client
        {
            ClientId = "client",
            ClientName = "Client Credentials Client",

            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
            ClientSecrets = { new Secret("511536EF-F270-4058-80CA-1C89C192F69A".Sha256()) },

            AllowedScopes = { "LicenseAPI" }
        },
    }
}
```

My goal is to rewrite my different websites (homepage, shop, blog, etc.) in dotnet core and to bring them under one roof. Currently they run under different systems, at different hosters, etc.

I would like to have a central application (homepage) (for example as MVC Web App), where users can register and log in and implement all other websites as Web APIs, which are called from the central application. I would like to have separate apps to be able to maintain them separately.

- central MVC or JS App (Homepage)
- Web API (Shop)
- Web API (Blog)
- Web API (...)
- Web API (IdentityServer)

I would like to use IdentityServer as authentication of the registered and authorized users when calling the Web APIs. In my design vision as a separate service. Additionally I want to use dotnet core IdentityUser.

My understanding problem now is where I store my user data? As I understand it, users register and log into my planned central application (homepage) and this data is stored in the database of this application.  But how does the separate IdentityServer service learn from my users and how does it access them? How, for example, does it access the claims, etc? Does he use the same database?

For example, I need the IdentityServer to send additional information (claims) with the token. For example, user IDs, which I then use in the requests to my Web APIs or which the IdentityServer sends along with the IDs in the token, requestet by the APIs.

As easy as the first Quickstarts were to understand, the more confused I am about the usage in my planned scenario (which shouldn't be unusual, I think) when handling the user credentials.

I would be grateful for pushing me in the right direction.

Comment: Just a comment, the example you give for getting an access token is for machine-to-machine communication (i.e.a client) rather than what you'd want to use for a user logging in. With the user logging in grant types (password, hybrid, implicit ...) you would then be able to make user_info calls to identity server to get details about the user. The access token from a client_credentials call will have absolutely no context about a user (user id etc) as you've noticed.

Comment: Yes, that was just an example what I understood of the quickstarts and that is is explicitely for m2m communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding problem now is where I store my user data?

The `User`, `Client` and `Resource` stores are really up to you to implement whichever way you choose. Identity Server 4 comes with EF Core & ASP.Net Identity support out of the box so if you choose to use database for your persistence layer implementation.

> But how does the separate IdentityServer service learn from my users
>   and how does it access them?

Well, if for example you choose to go with ASP.NET Identity system for your user management, then all you would need to is to point the Identity Server to the same database as your user registration web app (it may even be the same app as well). In general, the user store that identity server uses for the purposes of user profile data & credential verification will have to be the same as whatever you choose to implement your user registration platform on.

> For example, I need the IdentityServer to send additional information
>   (claims) with the token.

This is not really a problem, you might need to implement custom `IProfileService` and `GetProfileDataAsync` in order to control the custom claims that are issued. More info at [IdentityServer4 docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/profileservice.html).

Comment: Thanks, the "both use the same user store" was the link I was missing.

Comment: @Igotcha no problems, you are welcome, mark the answer as accepted if it has helped you.

Comment: Exactly what I needed...